# Wordress website infinitly reloads when changing the site and wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, dns

After a few days of looking around and trying, I do not seem any closer to the solution.

I am running a nginx + WordPress site off of one of my machines. I recently bought a domain name through domain.com. Currently I have my external IP set as both the site and WordPress URL. This works alright but if i try to connect to my domain name and subsequently click on any page of my website, the domain name in the url will be replaced by my external IP. However if I exchange the site and WordPress URL for my domain name (http://domain.xyz) my main page will infinitely reload and my admin panel will no longer be accessible.

How do i achieve the expected site behavior of http://domain.xyz/url, as opposed to http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/url ?

thanks for any info you can provide!

Comment: Please share your nginx configuration.... otherwise trying to help is very complicated and will be based more on guessing what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's a wrong URL anywhere in the WordPress configs, so here are a few ideas of what could be the issue and how to solve it:

### WP Options

Check for the correct URL in your database. In the table, `wp_options`, are 2 entries (`siteurl` and `home`) with the URL. Make sure that `option_value` is equal to your path, in your example `http://domain.xyz/url`.

### WordPress Permalinks

If you moved from one domain to another or the directory of WordPress changed, try to reload the Permalink Structure: /wp-admin/ -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save

### SSL, www.

Also, make sure you have the correct URL entered. For example, if you're using SSL, don't use `http://example.com/url` but `https://example.com/url`.

Same thing for the www. subdomain if you're using it (or any other subdomain).

Comment: .htaccess will not work with NGINX... please update your suggested answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately NGINX indeed does not have this file.